# Narrowing object value type based on function parameter

Tags: typescript

So, I have enums:

```
export enum FilterName {
  Date = 'date',
  State = 'state',
}

export enum FilterField {
  CreatedAtStartDate = 'createdAtStartDate',
  CreatedAtEndDate = 'createdAtEndDate'
  State = 'state',
}

export type TDateFields = {
  min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate;
  max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate;
};
```

I have function:

```
export const getFilterField = (filterName: FilterName) =>
  ({
    [FilterName.Date]: {
      min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate,
      max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate,
    } as TDateFields,
    [FilterName.State]: FilterField.State,
  }[filterName]);
```

Now, I call the function like this:

```
const filterFields = getFilterField(FilterName.Date);
```

Doing `filterFields.min` will throw an error:

```
Property 'min' does not exist on type 'FilterField | TDateFields'
```

I can solve this by doing `const filterFields = getFilterField(filterName) as TDateFields`, but I would like to have type narrowing. Is that possible in a case like this and if yes, how?

Comment: You don't have a CreatedAtEndDate in your enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your JSON key/value object to a type, and for a bonus, use generics to change the return type depending on the enum type.

```
export enum FilterName {
  Date = 'date',
  State = 'state',
}

export enum FilterField {
  CreatedAtStartDate = 'createdAtStartDate',
  CreatedAtEndDate = 'createdAtEndDate',
  State = 'state',
}

export type TDateFields = {
  min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate;
  max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate;
};

interface FieldData {
    [FilterName.Date]: TDateFields,
    [FilterName.State]: FilterField.State
}

export function getFilterField<T extends FilterName>(filterName: T): FieldData[T] {
  const data: FieldData = {
    [FilterName.Date]: {
      min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate,
      max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate,
    } as TDateFields,
    [FilterName.State]: FilterField.State,
  }

  return data[filterName]
}

const filterFields = getFilterField(FilterName.Date);

let min = filterFields.min
// ^? let min: FilterFIelds.CreatedAtStartData
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsA2NhQByAhqsHAN4BQccAIsfnALxwDkAJo8GwDQ1wAyjG4t2AZxH4%20VAL5UqoSLAQp02PAWzAcHSgIDCUYNw4BBGMOKwGTVmwDGx0xas3uM2kZP5zMAKKIHLbk9k4%20wH6BwR78tFZ2ElI8-PKK4NDwMACeYOQAKiHauuJi1LSoWIgAXJi4%20FDFHAB03i6WIu74ANwCqMQgtRoNTa3OvhbRIb2yvVRVDQBmxA7kTbbE%20rS0ANrDBCRkzSEAurWF3E3icdt79QekwM0JwGd1mo1YOi0vcgpKmTgi2QiAcMCwEEQcAA5sAYPtPt8ADz5BAgfBBUoIw7AAB8AApFvciI9zgBKIZfXQbHb5E5bOAOSGSOBcESU74bMoCXbYx7HbhvcrbCpVSkfUZtCYdawwEI3EX9QbvEZUlpSyKTILynlwWRwYilC74K4KuB3D4457JN4I0YvG5pWjGGDIKBQtnEHZEy2PE5-KhMxAsn2q76lViw%20HEpr4vlHEJkuY4OFwSpQ1ihrRq8TNdNUAD0BbgAD0APxAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can have no need for casting by using an overload:

```
export enum FilterName {
  Date = 'date',
  State = 'state',
}

export enum FilterField {
  CreatedAtStartDate = 'createdAtStartDate',
  CreatedAtEndDate = 'createdAtEndDate',
  State = 'state',
}

export type TDateFields = {
  min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate;
  max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate;
};

export function getFilterField (filterName: FilterName.Date): TDateFields
export function getFilterField (filterName: FilterName.State): { [FilterName.State]: FilterField.State }
export function getFilterField (filterName: FilterName) {
    switch (filterName) {
        case FilterName.Date:
          return {
            min: FilterField.CreatedAtStartDate,
            max: FilterField.CreatedAtEndDate,
          };
        
        case FilterName.State:
          return { [FilterName.State]: FilterField.State }

        // no need for a default case, the compiler understands
        // this is exhaustive
    }
};

// Has type TDateFields
const filterFields = getFilterField(FilterName.Date);

// No type error, compiler already narrowed during
// overload resolution.
filterFields.min;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsA2NhQByAhqsHAN4BQccAIsfnALxwDkAJo8GwDQ1wAyjG4t2AZxH4+VAL5UqoSLAQp02PAWzAcHSgIDCUYNw4BBGMOKwGTVmwDGx0xas3uM2kZP5zMAKKIHLbk9k4+wH6BwR78tFZ2ElI8-PKK4NDwMACeYOQAKiHauuJi1LSoWIgAXJi4+FDFHAB03i6WIu74ANwCqMQgtRoNTa3OvhbRIb2yvenK8ABmyIgOMFgQiHAA5sAww1pYOnoAFIv1BCRkQxdEpMDNIQCUtYXcTeLzmXDLq+ubOz2B0aR10cDOtyuwBumjuZGaCWAL0ocAA2sCoQjkgBdGEjUEtRFweRKb6-NYbLa7fa3Jrg86wqF4y73J76Wi0cQAdywMAcAAt6ZDWeyOWKHMRxOQMfdHtxqgIxWLjDBkFAtuUlVrKjU6rDRm0Jh1rDAQnEtUr+oM9fjjmMIlEgmbFRbZi6xe6ORKpTaWfDEQqLRyVWqNWiZf6ccyQXaifIxfI3VQHJtJD9aQTSqxqcCmicIw9nr0GbaSs0db0gA)

I took the liberty of adding the missing member of the one enum (see my comment on the question). Note also that there's no cast on the TDateFields return case anymore.